# Experience Profile search stops working when swapping xDB cores back

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1. I have a requirement to enable searching for a user with his name in the Experience Profile dashboard.

[image]
I followed [this link](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-pii-sensitive-data-in-the-xdb-index.html) in order to enable indexing PII data, then I followed the steps for rebuilding the xDB and it worked, I was able to search with a name in the Experience Profile and it returned the results.

But the thing is, when I did the last step in [this link](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html) which is swapping back the xdb cores, the search went back to **not** working again.

So my question, is this the expected behavior, that swapping back will disable the search functionality again and I should just keep the cores swapped in order for the search to keep working? or this might be an issue?
I can't see any relevant errors in the xConnect indexWorker logs.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are seeing the result after rebuilding the xDB index it means index rebuild is completed without error when the rebuild is complete, the cores are swapped and the rebuild core becomes the live core, you don't need to perform a swap manually here. You can confirm this by checking the physical folder location as when you swap cores, names are swapped, but physical folder locations are not swapped-

[image]

At this point, the rebuild core is no longer in use and having the old data in it if any. manuallly swapping will point the old core index. You should not manually swapping cores back if there is not any specific requirement.